# How do I load an assembly in app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, .net-assembly

Here is the full story:
I am trying to implement a custom appender for log4net. That appender used to be in the same project as the App.config and everything was working great, but now I moved it in another project (class library) which I am referencing. The name of my shared project is Lib and my appender is contained in the Lib namespace so I reference it that way:

```
<appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="Lib.ConsoleAppenderWithColorSwitching">
```

log4net tells me that my Lib isn't loaded into the assembly, here is the exact error:

> log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [ColoredConsoleAppender] of type [Lib.ConsoleAppenderWithColorSwitching]. Reported error follows.
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type [Lib.ConsoleAppenderWithColorSwitching]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a] and all loaded assemblies

Right at the start of my program I have checked the loaded assemblies using:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

And my library is indeed not loaded.

How can I load my class library so I can use my appender in my App.config file?

Comment: Where is the DLL? is it in the application's executable folder? If not: Is it in the GAC? If not, how do you think it will be found?

Comment: The DLL is indeed in the executable folder since I am referencing it from my other project.

Comment: That's not necessarily so, but good you solved it yourself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve my problem by specifying the assembly after the name of the type:

```
<appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="Lib.ConsoleAppenderWithColorSwitching, Lib">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using an Assembly qualified name. For example for class Namespace.SomeClass in assembly MyLib the assembly qualified name would be Namespace.SomeClass, MyLib.

This will only work if MyLib is in the GAC, the application directory, or one of the specified private binary subdirectories of the app.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx for more on fully qualified names.

There are many other mechanisms for loading assemblies but for the purposes of loading via a config file an assembly qualified name should work.